# Partial function application for a non-symmetric operator using point-free style in F#?

Tags: f#, pointfree

How can I create a partial function application for a non-symmetric operator such as the modulus operator with regards to the first argument without any argument names in F#? My first attempt was

`let mod10 = (%) 10` which of course translates to

`mod10(x) = 10 mod x` instead of the desired

`mod10(x) = x mod 10`.
Certainly I could write

`let mod10 x = (%)x 10` but I'd like to not have to name the argument so is there some placeholder that can be used, something like

`let mod10 = (%)_ 10`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define `flip` function which is common in point-free style:

```
let inline flip f x y = f y x
```

and use it like this:

```
let (%-) = flip (%)
let mod10 = (%-) 10
```

or directly like this:

```
let mod10 = flip (%) 10
```

Point-free style is not always readable (as in this example) and not popular in F# programming.

Comment: Ah nice 'trick'! I agree that point-free style isn't always readable but I guess that goes for all styles.

Comment: Programming isn't really a popularity contest. Besides, it's hard to make a call on popularity. It might be _uncommon_ but that doesn't mean it's unpopular. I like point-free in many cases, but in others it does reduce readability.

Comment: @pad: Our programming lives are full of subjectivity aren't they? :) That's what makes the world colourful!

Answer (score 20):

Here's solution based on functional composition.

```
let mod10 = (%) >> (|>) 10
```

**UPD** Here was a wordy explanation, but programmers speak the code, so I guess the following will describe it much better, in a manner of mathematical proof.

**The following expressions are equal**:

```
let m1 x = x % 10                    
let m2 x = (%) x 10                  // x (op) y = (op) x y
let m3 x = ((%) x) 10                // f x y = (f x) y
let m4 x = 10 |>         ((%) x)     // f x = x |> f
let m5 x = ((|>) 10)     ((%) x)     // x |> f = (|>) x f
let m6 x = ((%) x)    |> ((|>) 10)   // f x = x |> f
let m7 x = (x |> (%)) |> ((|>) 10)   // (op) x = x |> (op)
let m8 x = x |> ((%)  >> ((|>) 10))  // f(x) |> g = x |> (f >> g)
let m9   =       (%)  >> ((|>) 10)   // remove formal argument
let m10  =       (%)  >>  (|>) 10    // remove unnecessary parenthesis
```

Alternative syntax:

```
let mod10_2 = (|>) 10 << (%)
```

Comment: Truly awesome proof! The solution somewhat hard to decipher for a novice like myself but still, very beautiful :)

Comment: @Christian: It can be chained as well: `let combinator (b: 'b) (c: 'c) (f: 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) : ('a -> 'd) = f >> ((|>) b) >> ((|>) c)`