# Is there an infix function composition operator in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries, ocaml-core

Just a quick question. I'm wondering if there is a infix function composition operator in OCaml defined in the standard library (or in Jane Street's Core or in Batteries) like the (.)  function in Haskell which saves us a lot parentheses since we can write `(f . g . h) x` instead of the less appealing `f (g (h x)))`.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer here is the same as for `flip` :-). Function composition isn't defined in the OCaml standard library. In this case, it isn't something I miss once in a while, I miss it all the time.

The [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org) project defines function composition (in the order you give) using the operator `-|` in the [`BatStd`](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatStd.html) module. As lukstafi points out (see below), this operator will apparently change to `%` in a future release of Batteries. (I've verified this in their source tree.)

As far as I can see, the Jane Street [Core](http://janestreet.github.io) project doesn't define a function composition operator. It defines a function `compose` in the [`Fn`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Fn) module.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. You've been so helpful. I also haven't got access to their documentation at the moment.

Following your information, I've found anyway a `compose` function in the source file of Jane Street's Core.Std.Fn (c.f. https://github.com/janestreet/core/blob/master/lib/fn.mli, line 31).

Thank you.

Comment: FYI this is their traditional link for docs but it is down: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/

Comment: (Thanks; I'm waiting to see if it comes back up or if maybe there's a new link instead.)

Comment: The operators in [Batteries are changing](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batPervasives.mliv), see my [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410953/converting-f-pipeline-operators-to-ocaml/14414310#14414310).

Comment: I had the same problem looking for docs, they just never built them in the structure of their package tree. The new version released this morning has docs included though.

Comment: As pointed out by @mookid below, the standard library now supports the `(@@)` operator for function composition! It was added in 4.01.

Comment: The `@@` operator is not function composition. `@@` has this type: `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`. Function composition has this type: `('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b`. In fact @mookid mentions that infix composition is discouraged (something I never heard about). For what it's worth, SML has function composition as an infix operator `o`.

Comment: btw `%` there is no `BatStd` module at present, but `%` is available e.g. after executing `open Batteries`.

Comment: I agree that `@@` isn't function composition. Anyway, here's the link to the documentation: https://ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VAL(@@)

Answer (score 19):

I just want to add that the operator is fairly easy to include, in F# it's simply defined as:

```
let (<<) f g x = f(g(x));;
```

which has the type signature: `val ( << ) : f:('a -> 'b) -> g:('c -> 'a) -> x:'c -> 'b` doing exactly what you need...

```
(f << g << h) x = f(g(h(x))
```

so you don't need the batteries project if you don't have to

I'd like to add that the reason it looks like `<<` is, as you might guess, because the `>>` operator does the opposite:

```
let (>>) f g x = g(f(x));;

(f >> g >> h) x = h(g(f(x))
```

Comment: That's great. In OCaml, `>>` operator works perfectly. However, the `<<` operator completely hangs the interpreter. Why do you think this is?

Comment: I tested both definitions above, and I don't see any evidence for your claim. If you want a good answer you'll have to post a full question with some example code.

Comment: It looks like a token acceptance error. I defined the operators as above and `let f = (+) 1` and `let g = (*) 3`. At the REPL, `(f >> g) 10` is `33`. However, `(f << g) 10` apparently does not allow the interpreter to process the input because the `<<` token is bad (I had formerly thought that the REPL had hung but noticed the parse error when I tried to compile it from a file). This may be a result of `<<` being a reserved keyword (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#sec72), but for some reason `>>` works (for now). I'm running OCaml 4.01.0.

Comment: @BenSidhom, what I posted was just an example; you can just as easily use any other keyword I just used the F# ones because there's documentation on how they work.

Comment: I know, I was able to get it working by just using a different operator symbol. I was just confused as to why these strange problems were occurring. I imagine F# does not have issues with these symbols.

Comment: Nah, it goes around that by using `<<<` and `>>>` for bit-shifting instead of `<<` and `>>` like you normally see. The website you linked said `<<` and `>>` should be avoided for compatibility reasons. F# is a fairly isolated language; and as such doesn't have to worry about compatibility

Comment: There's now a very beginner friendly video demonstrating this method for ReasonML https://youtu.be/qZo-VWjC7es

Comment: Is not the real question about function composition, what the compiler (here, ocamlopt) will make of it?  Writing points free composition functions is fun and elegant - but at what cost? And how good is the compiler when it comes to loop fusion? (``x |> List.map f1 |> List.map f2`` optimized to ``x |> List.map (f1 >> f2)`` with all the benefits?

Answer (score 17):

There is `Fn.compose` function in Core, but it is not an infix operator. Also, it is implemented as a regular function and has runtime overhead.

In practice, it is pretty convenient to use pipe operator. It has no runtime overhead as implemented directly in compiler (starting from 4.00). See [Optimized Pipe Operators](https://www.ocamlpro.com/2012/08/20/ocamlpros-contributions-to-ocaml-4-00-0/) for more details.

Pipe operator is available as '|>' in Core. So, you can rewrite your expression as following: `h x |> g |> f`

Comment: Some people think the single pipe operator `|>` of Core is a good choice because it simplifies the number of infix operators you have to remember. In theory, you can have function composition and pipe operators, each in forward and reverse, so 4 total. But does that really help? Some view it as overkill and prefer having just `|>`.

Answer (score 12):

The use of an infix composition operator seems to be discouraged. (see [this discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/caml-list/0838.html)).

You can write `f @@ g @@ h x` instead of `f (g (h x)))`.

Answer (score 3):

In [Containers](https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-containers) (yet another stdlib replacement for Ocaml), the function composition operator is called `%` and can be found in the [CCFun](https://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/last/containers/CCFun/index.html) module:

```
open Containers
open Fun

let is_zero n = (n = 0)

let nonzeros = List.filter (not % is_zero) [0;1;2;3;0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that could help you.

```
let identite f = f
let (>>) = List.fold_right identite
```

test:

```
# let f=fun x-> x+1 and
      g=fun x-> x*2 and
      h=fun x-> x+3;;

# [f;g;h] >> 2;;
- : int = 11
```